# Database Project copy table while deploying

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio 2013

SQL Server 2008

Target Framework: .Net 3.5

I create a SQL Server database project and it worked fine. But I add a partition Function and Partition schema [PS], and change one of my tables: delete clustered primary key and add clustered index on new PS:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [Ind_Archive_Data]
ON [Archive].[Data]([Id] ASC, [CreatedOn] ASC)
ON [RangePS] ([CreatedOn])
```

After that, copy of table [Archive].[Data] creates each time when i redeploy the project:

```
CREATE TABLE [Archive].[tmp_ms_xx_Data]....
INSERT INTO [Archive].[tmp_ms_xx_Data]...copy data...
DROP TABLE [Archive].[Data];
EXECUTE sp_rename N'[Archive].[tmp_ms_xx_Data]', N'Data';
```

Even if I do not make any changes in this table. And even worse - it's copying it twice during one deployment: first time as I show above, and the second - recreates table in the same manner and creates the copy of index [Ind_Archive_Data].

And it's bad, because my Data table potentially could be quite large.
I run Shema Compare: database have a lot more objects, but tables that i try to deploy - absolutely identical.

Could someone, please, explain this behavior and how can i fix it.

Comment: Not sure, if it would be useful for somebody. But just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I'm generating deployment script from my dacpac file looks like this:

```
sqlpackage.exe /Action:script /sourcefile:J:\path\to\My.dacpac /targetservername:localhost /targetdatabasename:ArchiveDB /v:Environment=DEV /v:Revision=1.1.0.0 /OutputPath:J:\test\ResultingScript.sql /v:ServiceUser=domain\user /v:ApiUser=domain\user /v:CsapiUser=domain\user /p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=True /p:IgnorePartitionSchemes=false
```

The problem was in last parameter. By default, for some reason, it's not only true, but also always detect some differences in my schema.

For additional info about this parameners you could check:

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx
2. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/01a9fbae-c143-45b1-bbdd-e1a1cddba042/sqlpackage-rebuild-the-table?forum=ssdt